# How to remove the uploaded file while deleting the respective row value in sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, upload

How to delete the uploaded file on Symfony Sonata admin bundle? I have already tried this code on admin class it does not work.

```
public function removeUpload() {
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
public function getAbsolutePath() {
    return "uploads/" . getFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the uploaded file on the sonata admin bundle we use the postRemove action

```
        function     postRemove($object){
$image    =     ' Your path';
@unlink($image);
}
```